# How sandbox solutions are migrated from SP2010 to SP2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sandbox-solution

Can anyone tell me what happens to Sandbox solutions when migrating from SP2010 to SP2013. I know that sandbox solutions are depricated in SP2013, so how are they going to work in SP2013.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Only Sandbox solutions with sandboxed code(C# code) is deprecated. **Sandbox solutions with declarative elements and pages with java script etc are NOT Deprecated**. So if your solution is having only declarative code to provision things and pages with javascript etc, it can be very well used in SP2013 as Sandbox package. But if you have any custom C# code then you should consider rewriting it as an App.

Check this [Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx) for more details